# Replace app on AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an app on AppStore that I would like to improve with StoryBoard. I was recomended to build a new app from scratch instead of trying to add storyboard to an old app. So I have done that and now I would like to upload it to the AppStore and replace the old one.

I understand that the bundle identifier and app name must be the same. Do I have to make sure any other stuff is the same?

Comment: The key to sign the app should be also the same I guess.

Comment: I don't think it's standard practice to replace your app with a new version of it. It's intended for updates. The worst case scenario would be to reject your old app and thereafter re-upload your new package. But im not certain if you can use the same bundle identifier nor the name for the app.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can do this no problem.

Just make sure to use the same App bundle identifier i.e. com.companyname.appname as in your original app.

Then use the same distribution license that you would normally use.

You have to release the new app as an update to the old app but apart from that you can change anything else.

You also have to make the new version number greater than the current apps version number.

To the users it will look like a normal update but in the background you will have essentially replaced the entire app.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider this as an update of you app.

`Bundle version` should be higher then before (for example 1.1 or 2.0 if the previous one is 1.0) - this usually depends on how big the difference will seem to the users.

And also: if you are saving anything to `documents` folder make sure that the new version is compatible with the old data.

New version should be able to run on device:

- if there was (any) previous version installed
- if there was no previous installation of your app